# Explain Imaginary Time and Temperature

Tags: quantum-field-theory, temperature, time, complex-numbers, wick-rotation

I was amazed to learn that we can use Imaginary unit iota into physical quantities like time and Temperature but how exactly?

The explanation was not something I would say stellar so I am hoping can anyone explain Imaginary Time and Temperature and other Imaginary physical quantities wrt quantum mechanics and what is wick's rotation?

Comment: Where have you seen time or temperature expressed as an imaginary number?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the physical interpretation of the Wick rotation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/473012/)